# Message Box displays with no spaces?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, message

When I click a button I want a message box to pop up with the employee with the lowest salary. These employees are inputted via textboxes and stored in array. The class is called "Employee".

I've gotten it to work but for example if I entered ID: 1234, firstname: Bob, lastname: Styles, Salary: 24, the messagebox displays : "1234BobStyles24" with no spaces. How can I fix this? Here's my code:

```
    private void lowestSalaryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal minSalary = employees.Min(em => em.YearSalary);
        IEnumerable<Employee> poors = employees.Where(em => em.YearSalary == minSalary);
        poors.Count();
        foreach (var poor in poors)
        MessageBox.Show(minSalary.ToString("C") + poor.FirstName + poor.LastName +   
        poor.EmployeeId, "Min salary");

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change it to this :

```
MessageBox.Show(minSalary.ToString("C") + " " + poor.FirstName  + " " + poor.LastName  + " " + poor.EmployeeId, "Min salary");
```

Or a better way would be :

```
string message = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", minSalary, poor.FirstName, poor.LastName, poor.EmployeeId);

MessageBox.Show(message, "Min salary");
```

Answer (score 2):

Somethign like this:

```
      string spaceInBetween  =new string(' ', 2);
      MessageBox.Show(minSalary.ToString("C") + 
                  spaceInBetween   +  poor.FirstName + 
                  spaceInBetween   + poor.LastName +  
                  spaceInBetween + poor.EmployeeId, "Min salary");
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
 MessageBox.Show(minSalary.ToString("C") + poor.FirstName + poor.LastName +   
        poor.EmployeeId, "Min salary");
```

You do exactly that

You can either use a

```
String.Format(" {0} {1} [2} {3}, Min salary",minSalary.ToString("C"), poor.FirstName , poor.LastName ,  poor.EmployeeId )
```

or, you add your own spaces with

```
poor.Firstname + " " + poor.Lastname
```